# IF condition in Linq

Tags: linq

how to use If condition in this LINQ

```
    public Student SearchStudentStatus()
    {
        students=from stud in students
               let status=(stud.Status=="PASS")?true:false

        return students;
    }
```

If the status is true(PASS), then check for Student's birthday, if it is today then take it otherwise don't take it

Comment: What means "then take it"? You want to get students which have a given student-id and who's birthday is today?

Comment: What does it mean to check for student's birthday?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to show only students which status is `"PASS"` and which have birthday today?

```
public List<Student> SearchStudentStatus()
{
    return students
         .Where(s => s.Status == "PASS" && s.Birthday.Date == DateTime.Today)
         .ToList();
}
```

Comment: maybe but then what's the use of the stUdentID filter?

Comment: @vc74: no idea, but it's not my filter. Op has added it to his original question. I will edit my answer as well.

Comment: sorry, I missed the original question. I'm picky and curious but does Birthday contain birth date + time or do you mean s.Birthday == DateTime.Today?

Comment: @Time anyway, you get my vote for OP question deciphering ;)

Comment: @vc74: i don't know since OP hasn't mentioned it. Maybe `Birtday` contains the time. That's why i've used `Birthday.Date` to prevent follow-up questions ;)

Comment: @vc74: Birthdat==DateTime.Today